# Normal Distribution in R. Finding P

Tags: r, statistics, gaussian

I'm having trouble solving a normal distribution problem in R. I'm unfamiliar with the syntax and would like some help.

```
If X~N(2,9), compute       
a. P(X>=2)    
b. P(1<=X<7)    
c. P(-2.5<=X<-1)    
d. P(-3<=X-2<3)
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a homework problem in statistics. (That was not the majority justification.)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `pnorm` function. This is the normal CDF. So you want to do something like:

```
# A
1 - pnorm(2, mean = 2, sd = 9) # = 0.5
# B
pnorm(7, mean = 2, sd = 9) - pnorm(1, mean = 2, sd = 9) # =  0.255
```

I think you can figure out the last two yourself.

Comment: I thought your answer was tangential.

Comment: @user3635123 Add 2 on both sides of the inequalities.

Comment: @BondedDust Sorry. I can't help it. :)

Comment: You shouldn't use 1-pnorm. Instead adjust lower.tail accordingly.